# How to detect and display for unsigned overflow hex values in C++

Tags: c++, overflow

The program needs to compute 5 calculations of Hex numbers which I have done already. What I can't get though is how to find out if overflow has occurred, and if it has, how can I display that to the user? I want it to say something like "Overflow detected <Yes/No>" Code attached.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

uint32_t add(uint32_t num1, uint32_t num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}
int main() {

    ifstream inputFile("input.txt");
    string line;

    while(getline(inputFile, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        string operation, hexNum1, hexNum2;

        iss >> operation >> hexNum1 >> hexNum2;

        uint32_t num1 = stoul(hexNum1, nullptr, 16);
        uint32_t num2 = stoul(hexNum2, nullptr, 16);
        
        uint32_t result = add(num1, num2);

        cout << "ADD " << hexNum1 << " " << hexNum2 << " = " << "0x" << hex << result << endl;

    }
    inputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't even really know where to start for finding overflow, from what I have read, C does not actually have a way of storing overflow and you must find it before the computation happens.

Comment: You can't detect that unsigned overflow has occurred., You have to determine whether the operation you're about to do will overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Found this 15 years old question here: [How do I detect unsigned integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-overflow)

You can adapt the very first answer to unsigned inegers, something like this:

```
if (num1 > UINT_MAX - num2) // `num1 + num2` would overflow
```

Comment: This worked! I put the function right underneath the cout << "ADD " << hexNum1... line. It worked exactly as it should have. Thank you so much.